# search method not reRender and not working (Communicate between two component and parent page)

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

this is my page

```
<apex:page controller="contactcloudcontroller" showHeader="true" tabStyle="contact" rendered="true">
<apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock id="pgBlock">
      <c:searchComponent idx="1"/>
  </apex:pageBlock>

  <apex:outputPanel id="pgBlock2">
      <c:paginationComponent idx="1"/>
  </apex:outputPanel>

  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

this is my searchComponent

```
<apex:component controller="contactcloudcontroller" allowDML="true" rendered="true" >
<apex:attribute name="idx" type="string" description="Unique index for this component in the page" />
   <apex:pageMessages />
 <apex:actionFunction name="searchData{!idx}" action="{!search}" reRender="pgBlock2"/>
      <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" collapsible="true">
          <apex:inputField value="{!con.firstname}"/>
          <apex:inputField value="{!con.lastname}" required="false"/>
          <apex:inputField value="{!con.email}"/>
          <apex:inputField value="{!con.phone}"/>
          <apex:inputField value="{!con.MailingState}"/>
          <apex:inputField value="{!con.MailingCity}"/>
          <apex:inputField value="{!con.Accountid}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>

      <apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!save}"/>
      <apex:commandButton value="search" onclick="searchData{!idx}();"/>
 </apex:component>
```

this is my paginationComponent

```
<apex:component controller="contactcloudcontroller">
<apex:attribute name="idx" type="string" description="Unique index for this component in the page" />
 <apex:pageBlock id="pgBlock">
 <style> 
     #t:hover{
                background-color: #87cefa;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
   </style> 
    <table width="100%" style="font-size: 12pt; border: 1pt solid black;">
        <tr bgcolor="#87cefa">
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>City</th>
        </tr>
          <apex:repeat value="{!clist}"  var="cont">
            <tr id="t">
                  <td><apex:outputText value="{!cont.firstname}" /></td>
                  <td><apex:outputText value="{!cont.lastname}"/></td>
                  <td><apex:outputText value="{!cont.email}"/></td>
                  <td><apex:outputText value="{!cont.phone}" /></td>
                  <td><apex:outputText value="{!cont.mailingstate}"/></td>
                  <td><apex:outputText value="{!cont.mailingCity}"/></td>
             </tr>
        </apex:repeat>
    </table>

     <apex:pageblockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton value="First Page" rerender="pgBlock" action="{!FirstPage}" disabled="{!prev}" immediate="true"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Previous" action="{!Previous}" immediate="true" rerender="pgBlock" disabled="{!prev}" />
        <apex:commandButton value="Next" action="{!Next}" immediate="true" rerender="pgBlock" disabled="{!nxt}"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Last Page" rerender="pgBlock" action="{!LastPage}" disabled="{!nxt}" immediate="true"/>

   </apex:pageblockButtons>
   </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:component>
```

this is my class

```
public class contactcloudcontroller {
    public contact con{get;set;}
    public list<contact> clist{get;set;}
    public Integer CountTotalRecords=0;
    public Integer OffsetSize = 0;
    public Integer QueryLimit = 10;

    public contactcloudcontroller() {
        con=new contact();  
        clist=new list<contact>();
        CountTotalRecords= [select count() from Contact];
        getContact();
        system.debug('**'+CountTotalRecords);

    }
   // system.debug('**'+CountTotalRecords);
    public pageReference save() {
        if (con.lastname == null){
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Please enter Last Name'));
            return null;
        } 
        insert con;
        pageReference pg=new pageReference('/'+con.id).setRedirect(true);
        return pg;
    }
    public void search() {
        String Query='select FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone, MailingState, MailingCity from contact';
        boolean whereflag=false;
        if(con.firstname !=null){
            Query+=' where firstname like \''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(con.firstName)+'%\'';
            whereFlag=true;
        }
        if(con.lastname !=null){
            if(whereFlag){
                Query+=' and ';
            }
            else{
                Query+=' where ';
                whereFlag=true;
             }
             Query+=' lastname like \''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(con.lastName)+'%\'';
         }
         if(con.email !=null) {
            if(whereFlag){
                Query+=' and ';
            }
            else {
                Query+=' where ';
                whereFlag=true;
             }
             Query+=' email like \''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(con.email)+'%\'';
         }
          if(con.phone !=null) {
            if(whereFlag){
                Query+=' and ';
            }
            else {
                Query+=' where';
                whereFlag=true;
             }
             Query+=' phone like \''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(con.phone)+'%\'';
         }
         if(con.MailingState !=null) {
            if(whereFlag){
                Query+=' and ';
            }
            else {
                Query+=' where ';
                whereFlag=true;
             }
             Query+=' MailingState like \''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(con.MailingState)+'%\'';
         }
         if(con.MailingCity !=null) {
            if(whereFlag){
                Query+=' and ';
            }
            else {
                Query+=' where ';
                whereFlag=true;
             }
             Query+=' MailingCity like \''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(con.MailingCity)+'%\'';
         }
             system.debug('@@'+Query);
             clist=Database.query(Query);
             system.debug('@@@@@'+clist);
   }
   public void getContact() {
       clist= [select FirstName, LastName,email, Phone, MailingState, MailingCity from Contact limit :QueryLimit offset :OffsetSize]; 
   }
    public void FirstPage(){
        OffsetSize = 0;
        getContact();
    }
    public void Next() {
        OffsetSize = OffsetSize+QueryLimit;
        getContact();
    }

    public void Previous() {
        OffsetSize = OffsetSize-QueryLimit;
        getContact();
    }
    public void LastPage(){
        OffsetSize = CountTotalRecords - math.mod(CountTotalRecords,QueryLimit);
        getContact();
    }
    public boolean getprev() {
        if(OffsetSize == 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    public boolean getnxt() {
        if((OffsetSize + QueryLimit) > CountTotalRecords)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: pgBlock id is given in apex:form is duplicate in component and in page. It might be the cause for the form not being rerendered. Also, it is not advisable to have mutliple forms in the same page. Can you substitute the apex:form in component with an outputPanel tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify you **page** and **component** to communicate like below example..

In you page first pass the list and action that required for component..

```
<apex:page controller="contactcloudcontroller" showHeader="true" tabStyle="contact" rendered="true"> 
<apex:form > 
<apex:pageBlock id="searchComponentId"> 
    <c:searchComponent myContact="{!con}" mySaveAction="{!save}" mySearchAction="{!search}"/> 
</apex:pageBlock> 

<apex:outputPanel id="paginationComponentId"> 
    <c:paginationComponent myConlist="{!clist}" myFirstPageAction="{!FirstPage}" 
            myPreviousAction="{!Previous}" myNextAction="{!Next}" myLastPageAction="{!LastPage}"/>
</apex:outputPanel> 

</apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

**In your pagination** create attributes that will call the controller methods...

```
<apex:component controller="contactcloudcontroller">
    <apex:attribute name="myConlist" description="This is the value for the component." type="Contact[]" required="true"/>
    <apex:attribute name="myFirstPageAction" description="FirstPage action" type="ApexPages.Action" required="true"/>
    <apex:attribute name="myPreviousAction" description="Previous action" type="ApexPages.Action" required="true"/>
    <apex:attribute name="myNextAction" description="Next action" type="ApexPages.Action" required="true"/>
    <apex:attribute name="myLastPageAction" description="LastPage action" type="ApexPages.Action" required="true"/>
    <apex:pageBlock id="pgBlock">
        <style>
            #t:hover {
                background-color: #87cefa;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
        </style>
        <table width="100%" style="font-size: 12pt; border: 1pt solid black;">
            <tr bgcolor="#87cefa">
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>State</th>
                <th>City</th> 
            </tr>
            <apex:repeat value="{!myConlist}" var="cont">
                <tr id="t">
                    <td>
                        <apex:outputText value="{!cont.firstname}" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <apex:outputText value="{!cont.lastname}" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <apex:outputText value="{!cont.email}" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <apex:outputText value="{!cont.phone}" />
                    </td> 
                    <td>
                        <apex:outputText value="{!cont.mailingstate}" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <apex:outputText value="{!cont.mailingCity}" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
        </table>

        <apex:pageblockButtons>
            <apex:commandButton value="First Page" rerender="pgBlock" action="{!myFirstPageAction}" disabled="{!prev}" immediate="true" />
            <apex:commandButton value="Previous" action="{!myPreviousAction}" immediate="true" rerender="pgBlock" disabled="{!prev}" />
            <apex:commandButton value="Next" action="{!myNextAction}" immediate="true" rerender="pgBlock" disabled="{!nxt}" />
            <apex:commandButton value="Last Page" rerender="pgBlock" action="{!myLastPageAction}" disabled="{!nxt}" immediate="true" />

        </apex:pageblockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:component>
```

**Same for Search component** create attributes for object and methods

```
<apex:component>
    <apex:attribute name="myContact" description="This is the value for the component." type="Contact" required="true"/>
    <apex:attribute name="mySaveAction" description="save action" type="ApexPages.Action" required="true"/>
    <apex:attribute name="mySearchAction" description="save action" type="ApexPages.Action" required="true"/>
    <apex:outputPanel>
        <apex:pageMessages />
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" collapsible="true">
            <apex:inputField value="{!myContact.firstname}" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!myContact.lastname}" required="false" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!myContact.email}" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!myContact.phone}" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!myContact.MailingState}" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!myContact.MailingCity}" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!myContact.Accountid}" />
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!mySaveAction}" />
        <apex:commandButton value="search" action="{!mySearchAction}" rerender="paginationComponentId"/>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:component>
```

Comment: i have placed your code but still searching is not working

Comment: i have placed your code error occur
Error: Unknown property 'contactcloudcontroller.idx'
on page
<apex:page controller="contactcloudcontroller" showHeader="true" tabStyle="contact" rendered="true">
"<apex:form>
  <apex:pageBlock id="pgBlock2">
      <c:searchComponent/>
  </apex:pageBlock>
  
  <apex:outputPanel id="componentPanel1"> 
    <apex:actionFunction name="searchData{!idx}" action="{!search}" reRender="componentPanel1"/>
</apex:outputPanel>
  
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>

Comment: i have placed <apex:actionFunction name="searchData{!idx}" action="{!search}" reRender="componentPanel1"/> in component but its neither working nor giving error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34231/discussion-between-ratan-and-vipin-indora).

Comment: @VipinIndora most welcome..

Answer (score 0):

I think you also need to escape '%' in query where you are using LIKE operator. 
Can you surround the code in try catch block and print the error message in `catch block.`

```
 try{

 }catch{
     system.debug(e.getMessage() + e.getLineNumber());

 }
```